# Создание кроссплатформенного приложения на С#

Tags: c#, linux, xamarin

Подскажите, какой фреймворк наиболее предпочтительно использовать для создания и компиляции С# кода для операционных систем Windows и Linux в случае, когда приложение имеет сложную графическую часть и когда оно является консолью (под консолью в данном случае понимается приложение с минимальным графическим интерфейсом)? Подойдет ли Xamarin в одном из этих случаев? (Компиляция под операционные системы Android и IOs не интересует.)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Unity 3D? На самом деле я не знаю, как у него с линуксами

Comment: Используйте Avalonia

Answer (score 1):

Не так давно выпустили [muai](https://github.com/dotnet/maui).

Как написано в описаниии, это эволюция `Xamarin.Forms`. Есть возможность погрузиться и реализовать что нибудь

И дискуссию по этому поводу нашел [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/71). Возможны танцы с бубнами и трудности. Но можно вложиться в развитие, если кому интересно)

Comment: Он не поддерживает Linux

Comment: @andreymal приложил ссылочку

Comment: Кто бы что не говорил, но мауи - полумертвая технология. Майки в погоне за продажами своей винды решили не поддерживать линукс и снова выстрелят себе в ногу, прям точь в точь как и при создании шарпа с ориентировкой только на винду. в конечном итоге всё равно пришлось им сделать поддержку платформ. К слову о линуксе, напоминаю, что android основан на ядре Linux. Т.е у майков по сути была возможность поддерживать линукс без всяких проблем

Comment: maui выпускался с целью освободиться от легаси xamarin.forms, однако вышло то, что вышло: `"You don't need to rewrite your Xamarin.Forms apps to move them to .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI)."`

Answer (score 1):

Для настолок так: [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net/), [Eto](https://github.com/picoe/Eto), [Uno](https://platform.uno/)
Не совсем понял что подрозумеватся под фрейморком для консоли, но если что есть такая [либа](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs)